# jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?

Tags: jquery

How would I go about using `wrap()` to wrap multiple elements (with different classes) inside a `<div>`?

For example, on the form I'm working on there is a big list of checkbox inputs and labels in the form of:

```
<input>
<label>
<input>
<label>
```

etc

I'm wanting to wrap a `<div>` around the input and label, so the result would be:

```
<div>
  <input>
  <label>
</div>
<div>
  <input>
  <label>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the `.wrapAll()` method.

```
$('form > input').each(function(){
    $(this).next('label').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="test"/>');
});
```

If your markup has always the exact same order, I'd prefer to use:

```
var $set = $('form').children();    
for(var i=0, len = $set.length; i < len; i+=2){
    $set.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="test"/>');
}
```

Should be significant faster.

Ref.: [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/), [.andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/), [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: This is probably the best way of doing that.

Comment: Oddly enough, I just tried this on JS Fiddle, and it doesn't seem to work; however, James' answer, just below, does.

Comment: Hasn't what? Per the jQuery api docs: "This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later."

Comment: .andSelf() has been removed in jQuery 3.0. .addBack() needs to be used.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input+label').each(function(){
    $(this).prev().andSelf().wrapAll('<div>');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this:

```
<input id="input1">
<label id="label1">
<input id="input2">
<label id="label2">
```

Then you can use jQuery:

```
 jQuery("#input1").next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div id="newDiv" />');
 jQuery("#input2").next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div id="newDiv" />');
```

and get this:

```
<div id="newDiv">
  <input id="input1">
  <label id="label1">
</div>
<div id="newDiv">
  <input id="input2">
  <label id="label2">
</div>
```

Worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery function [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) allows you to wrap multiple elements but if you have a DOM like you wrote then it won't work too well as you can't easily match a part of label and input with a selector. I suggest adding some classes to each part and then using wrapAll.

```
<input class="i1"/>
<label class="i1"/>
<input class="i2"/>
<label class="i2"/>

$('.i1').wrapAll('<div/>');
$('.i2').wrapAll('<div/>');
```

This will give you

```
<div>
    <input class="i1"/>
    <label class="i1"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input class="i2"/>
    <label class="i2"/>
<div>
```