# JQuery: How to apply css to a .wrap element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

My code thus far:

```
$(".lorem img:not(.full-img)").each(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("inline-img");
    var imgWidth = $(this).prop('width');
    var imgHeight = $(this).prop('height');
    var imgFloat = $(this).prop('float');

    $(this).wrap('<div class="inline-img-wrap" />'); 
        if ($(this).prop("title")!='') {
            $('<p class="inline-img-caption">').text($(this).prop('title')).insertAfter($(this)); 
        }
});
```

I am searching for images within a body of text, appending their `title` values as captions underneath, and wrapping both `img` and `p` in a `div.inline-img-wrap`. That works fine.

What I need help with is applying the styling of the `img` to the new wrapping div instead. You can see I have created vars for just this, but cannot get applying them to work. `$this` will always apply to the image, and `<div class="inline-img-wrap" style="width:'+imgWidth+'">` doesn't work.

All advice appreciated!

Comment: Here is the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I get you right that you need to retrieve the newly created wrapping element?

```
var $wrap = $(this).wrap('<div class="inline-img-wrap" />').parent();
if ($(this).prop("title")!='') {
    $('<p class="inline-img-caption">').text($(this).prop('title')).appendTo($wrap); 
}
// do any other manipulations with $wrap
```

P.S. as a side-not: cache your jQuery objects - you are constantly calling $(this) wich is sub-optimal

Comment: My code is in another country from optimal - I'm only beginning, so it only visits optimal on holidays :) Let me try this out and make sure I understand its mechanics...

Answer (score 1):

try using `data` attribute and `css` method:

```
<img data-class='something'  src=''/>;
```

```
 $(".lorem img:not(.full-img)").each(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("inline-img");
    var imgWidth = $(this).css('width');
    var imgHeight = $(this).css('height');
    var imgFloat = $(this).css('float');

    $(this).wrap('<div class="inline-img-wrap + " " + $(this).data('class') + " />'); 
        if ($(this).prop("title")!='') {
            $('<p class="inline-img-caption">').text($(this).prop('title')).insertAfter($(this)); 
        }

    $("." + $(this).data('class')).css({"width": imgWidth, `height`: imgHeight, `float`: imgFloat})
});
```

Comment: Thank you, your's is actually closer to where I was heading myself, but Guard's is working fine for me now :)