# Jquery wrap elements inside div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add a div on the three following elements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <fieldset class="inner"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner first_name"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner last_name"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner user"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner password"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner avatar"></fieldset>
   <fieldset class="inner submit"></fieldset>
</div>
```

So the results are as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">

   <div class="inner-left">
      <fieldset class="inner"></fieldset>
      <fieldset class="inner first_name"></fieldset>
      <fieldset class="inner last_name"></fieldset>
      <fieldset class="inner user"></fieldset>
      <fieldset class="inner password"></fieldset>
   </div>

   <div class="inner-middle">
      <fieldset class="inner"></fieldset>
      <fieldset class="inner avatar"></fieldset>
   </div>

   <div class="inner-right">
      <fieldset class="inner submit"></fieldset>
   </div>

</div>
```

I've tried Jquery Multiple Wrap, but I can not implement it. 
can it be done with jQuery?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)?

Comment: show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.wrapAll()` in jquery. And `.slice()` split the dom elements what you want

```
$(".inner").slice(0,5).wrapAll( "<div class='inner-left'></div>" );
$(".inner").slice(5,7).wrapAll( "<div class='inner-middle'></div>" );
$(".inner").slice(7).wrapAll( "<div class='inner-right'></div>" );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyp3r/)

```
var cache = $( ".inner" )

cache.slice(0,5).wrapAll( "<div class='inner-left'></div>" )
     .end()
     .slice(5,7).wrapAll( "<div class='inner-middle'></div>" )
     .end()
     .slice(7).wrapAll( "<div class='inner-right'></div>" );
```

Comment: Please, please cache the result of `$(".inner")`, so you don't waste time matching the same elements again and again.

Comment: Hi, Sudharsan. 
This works for me, thank you for saving my time :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Don't use please in comment. We all are learn here that solve. Please delete the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:lt` and `:gt` pseudo selectors to get a range of elements, then `wrapAll` to put them in an element:

```
$('.inner:lt(5)').wrapAll($('<div>').addClass('inner-left'));
$('.inner:gt(4):lt(2)').wrapAll($('<div>').addClass('inner-middle'));
$('.inner:gt(6)').wrapAll($('<div>').addClass('inner-right'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7JY8p/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.inner:eq(0), .inner:eq(1), .inner:eq(2), .inner:eq(3), .inner:eq(4)').wrapAll( "<div class='inner-left'></div>");

$('.inner:eq(5), .inner:eq(6)').wrapAll( "<div class='inner-middle'></div>");

$('.inner:eq(7)').wrap( "<div class='inner-right'></div>");
```