# Wrap HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML element like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <div class="download-attr"></div>
    <div class="download-url"></div>
    <div class="download-ads"></div>
</div>
```

I want to wrap it looks like:

```
<div class="entry-content">    
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>    
    <div class="entry-content-left">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <div class="download-attr"></div>
        <div class="download-url"></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="entry-content-right">
        <div class="download-ads"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

How can I do it with jquery?

Comment: And your attempt for this....?

Comment: I've been attempt for this, I only understand if have a element in the same class like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323586/jquery-wrap-elements-inside-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how i'd do it:

```
$('.download-ads').wrap('<div class="entry-content-right"></div>');
$(".entry-content>*:not(p:first):not(div:last)").wrapAll('<div class="entry-content-left"></div>');
```

here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/Lu2pjm8e/

Comment: Got it! Thanks for you help :)

Comment: No problem.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
var content = $(".entry-content");
var lhs = $('<div class="entry-content-left"></div>');
var rhs = $('<div class="entry-content-right"></div>');
lhs.append($(".entry-content>*:not(p:first):not(div:last)")); //you can create a different selector for this task
rhs.append($(".entry-content .download-ads"));
content.append(lhs).append(rhs);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/953/