# How can I add a div around two elements yourself using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx8ksxn9/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="elm1"></div>
    <div class="elm2"></div>

    <div class="elm1"></div>
    <div class="elm2"></div>

    <div class="elm1"></div>
    <div class="elm2"></div>
</div>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$( "p" ).wrap( "<div></div>" );  //This is the function that can add a div element around element.
```

How can this fully to do what I want?

In the example above, is added a div to all the paragraph... I want to start div from `"elm1`" and closed at `"elm2".`

Can you help me please fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there are no `p` elements

Comment: I know, I just put the function that makes it ... no matter selector

Comment: @ArunPJohny he just giving an example o how wrap method works.

Comment: This question is a duplicated one. You can check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements

Comment: can anyone tell me how solve this problem in my code?
I looked in the example in response but failed to implement it