# Wrap two specific elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some elements like

```
<div id="one">ONE</div>
<div id="two">TWO</div>
<div id="three">THREE</div>
<div id="four">FOUR</div>
<div id="five">FIVE</div>
```

Now I want to wrap a DIV tag around the two elements with the ID "two" and "three" to get this:

```
<div id="one">ONE</div>
<div class="wrapped">
    <div id="two">TWO</div>
    <div id="three">THREE</div>
</div>
<div id="four">FOUR</div>
<div id="five">FIVE</div>
```

With the "wrapAll" function i can only target elements with the same class I think like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "div" ).wrapAll( "<div class='wrapped' />");
});
```

I know I could give the two DIVs the same class with jquery first and then wrap them but **I hope there is a more elegant way**.

Comment: `I want to wrap a DIV tag around the two elements with the ID "two" and "four"` Did you mean `two` and `three`? That's what your example would suggest. If so, use `$('#two, #three').wrapAll(...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)

Comment: Just use `$("#two, #three").wrapAll( "<div class='wrapped' />");` -- Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kgxpjhfu/)...

Comment: You just need to select DIVs two and three: `$("#two, #three).wrapAll...`  If it's more difficult than this, you'll need add more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `$('#two, #three').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />')`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6n9mn8cg/)**

Comment: Blarg, A minute too late.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace - blarg indeed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just select the the two you want and [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/).

From docs (emphasis my own):

> The .wrapAll() function can take any string or object that could be
>   passed to the $() function to specify a DOM structure. This structure
>   may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost
>   element. **The structure will be wrapped around all of the elements in**
>   **the set of matched elements, as a single group.**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/93dyokr0/1/

```
$('#two, #three').wrapAll( "<div class='wrapped' />");
```