# Wrap a bunch of different html tags with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about wrapping a bunch of HTML with one div with Jquery that looks like this?

```
<h2 id="1area">Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
<code></code>
<h2 id="2area">Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
<code></code>
```

Into

```
<div class="wrapit">
<h2 id="1area">Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
<code></code>
</div>

<div class="wrapitnumber2">
<h2 id="2area">Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
<code></code>
</div>
```

I want there to be two section labelled with different divs and classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question, try this:

```
$('h2').each(function(){
     $(this).nextUntil('h2').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapit"/>');
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, it's a case of traversing the DOM tree to select elements as appropriate and using the JQuery [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) function.

Example:

```js
$('h2').each(function(){
         $(this).nextUntil('h2').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapit"/>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
<h2>Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
<h2>Text</h2>
<p><strong>Step 1</strong></p>
<p><strong>Step 2</strong></p>
<p><img Step 1></p>
```

Comment: What If I were to add another few lines of code that includes h2 and p, and I want to wrap those as <div class=""wrapit1"> along with the previous wrapping? How would I select those specific h2 and p

Comment: I've updated the code segment.  There is a lot you can do with jQuery to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: I've updated my code as well, how would I make it look that way? I want it to have 2 different class names as oppose to the whole thing being wrapped by one. Thanks

Comment: I've figured it out using your code as guidelines. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it working! :) Could you mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you?