# Add a "wrapper" div tag to wrap other html div tags?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add a "wrapper" div tag to wrap two other tags with class name "c1" and "c2" with jQuery. please help me.

This is the code I have tried:

`$(".c1, .c2").wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>");`

I hope this code block will help you understand my demand:

```
<!--  This portion is my current code  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <div class="c3">c3</div>
    <div class="c4">c4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <div class="c3">c3</div>
    <div class="c4">c4</div>
</div>

{<div class="container"> ... </div>}n


<!--  This is my desired output  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="c1">c1</div>
        <div class="c2">c2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c3">c3</div>
    <div class="c4">c4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="c1">c1</div>
        <div class="c2">c2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c3">c3</div>
    <div class="c4">c4</div>
</div>

{<div class="container"> ... </div>}n
```

Final Target:
I just want to add a "wrapper" div around ".c1" & ".c2" with jQuery. Any idea will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) instead of [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```js
$(function() {
    $(".c1, .c2").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">c1</div>
    <div class="c2">c2</div>
    <div class="c3">c3</div>
    <div class="c4">c4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response, your solution did not work on my problem. the reason is; the portion where i commented "<!--  This portion is my current code  -->" is just a demo. i have the code block repeating at least 25-30 times per page. your solution takes all the "c1" & "c2" from other repeating portions and combine them together with "wrapper" div. But i want them to be separate like "<!--  This is my desired output  -->". hope fully i have succeeded to make you understand. Any further idea please...

Comment: @mishu36 In that case, I've linked your post with another post. Please see the link mentioned in comment below your post.

Comment: i have edited may question hopefully now it will be easier for you to understand my problem. the "container" div may occur any number of times in he same page. that why i have written 

{<div class="container"> ... </div>}n.

i used the "each" but no proper solution came out. please help .... 

thanks in advance......