# Create a new div and move the existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to create a new div and move the existing div into the newly created div.

This is my current div structure

```
<div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text2</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text3</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text4</div>
```

I want to create a new div `<div class="form-group"></div>` and move the `input-wrapper` div inside. So the new structure should look like this

```
<div class="form-group"><div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div></div>
<div class="form-group"><div class="input-wrapper">some text2</div></div>
<div class="form-group"><div class="input-wrapper">some text3</div></div>
<div class="form-group"><div class="input-wrapper">some text4</div></div>
```

I have used the following script

```
function create_structure(){
   $(".input-wrapper").append('<div class="form-group"></div>'); 
   $(".form-group").appendTo(".input-wrapper");      
};
window.setTimeout( create_structure, 2000 ); // 2 seconds
```

I am not getting the desired structure.

Anything I am missing in the code?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

how about using `wrap` method in jquery?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < $(".input-wrapper").length; i++) {
    $($(".input-wrapper")[i]).wrap("<div class='form-group'></div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text2</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text3</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text4</div>
```

Comment: if I also want to move existing span <span class="field-validation-valid"></span> next to input-wrapper div. What do I need to do?

Comment: @OwaisAhmed you mean `<span class="field-validation-valid"></span> <div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div>`  to `<div class="form-group"><span class="field-validation-valid"></span> <div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div></div>` ?

Comment: like this  <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div><span class="field-validation-valid"></span></div>

Comment: @OwaisAhmed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements this can be help for u

Answer (score 2):

Use the build-in `.each` in JQuery :

```js
$(".input-wrapper").each(function(i) {
   $(this).wrap("<div class='form-group'></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text1</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text2</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text3</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">some text4</div>
```

for your second Question about adding `<span>` you can achieve this by modifying my code to

```
$(".input-wrapper").each(function(i) {
   $(this).append("<span class='field-validation-valid'></span>");
   $(this).wrap("<div class='form-group'></div>");
});
```