# Wrap two words at different positions in html in one div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap two words in one div no matter their positions (so basically they're treated as "start" and "end" tags).

```
<p>Start Tag</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>End Tag</p>
```

The end result should be

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <p>Start Tag</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>End Tag</p>
</div>
```

I tried

```
$('p').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Start Tag') {
            $(this).before('<div class="wrapper">');
        }
        if ($(this).text() == 'End Tag') {
            $(this).after('</div>');
        }
    });
```

But for some reason it creates the whole div before the 'Start Tag' and does nothing after. I'm trying to split the " and the close tag "" so that it starts before the Start tag and ends after the End tag.

EDIT:
Found the solution as what I needed is that sometimes there are multiple of these:

```
$('p:contains("Start Tag")').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('p:contains("End Tag:")').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - use wrap() to wrap multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475594/jquery-use-wrap-to-wrap-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem (as I needed an expansive code that would work on multiple instances)

```
$('p:contains("Start Tag")').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('p:contains("End Tag")').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading your question, as I understand you asking to wrap your paragraph tags with the parent div class called wrapper.
**below code is your original code,**

```
<p>Start Tag</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>End Tag</p
```

**You need as result as below,**

```
**<div class="wrapper">
 <p>Start Tag</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>End Tag</p>
</div>**
```

In here you can get expected result using the wrapAll() jQuery function.
This is the answer,

```
<script>
  $("p").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>");
</script>
```

[here is the sandbox URL to play](https://codesandbox.io/s/wrap-parent-with-div-jquery-5428ww?file=/index.html)

Let understand this furthermore. let say your original html as below.

```
<p>Start Tag</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="third">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="third">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>End Tag</p>
```

And you need to wrap wrapper div with p tags class called third. you have to code as below.

```
<script>
  $(".third").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>");
</script>
```